# Necessary statements in the `__init__.py` file on definition of a Python package

Tags: python, python-module, pypi

I wrote a python module called [Eule](https://pypi.org/project/eule/). Yey! I had fun learning about some modern libraries like `poetry`, `ruff` and `sphinx` to organize the environment and make development life cycle easy. However, I do not know precisely what to place on [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/trouchet/eule/blob/master/eule/__init__.py) at main module folder.

As I posted above, I am able to import and use the library the way it is, but I still feel uncomfortable not knowing the best practices in this regard.

Comment: You don't *have* to put anything in the `__init__.py`

Comment: The presence of this file is used as the indicator that some directory represents a Python package. It should also contain any code which is necessary to execute first in order for the package to work correctly (similar to an `__init__` method of a type). Which is more often than not, no code at all.

Comment: Great. I removed all the code existent on it and it works well. Thanks, guys!